# Unable to find a role by its name

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a command where you can set up an LFG role (LFG = looking for game).

Right now, I need the bot to find a role by its name, but it doesn't work. I have no idea why, I have tried many other thing like finding the role by its ID or structuring the code differently but nothing... Heres is the code:

```js
collector1.on('collect', () => {
  // Si l'utilisateur a cliqué sur 1️⃣  LFG
  message.reactions.removeAll();

  const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(
      `**--------------------LFG role configuration--------------------**`,
    )
    .addField(
      `You clicked on 1️⃣`,
      `Send in the next 30 the name of the new LFG role.`,
      true,
    )
    .addField(
      `Missclicked?`,
      `Wait 30 seconds for the bot to send a timeout message and try again.`,
      true,
    );

  let filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
  m.edit(embed1).then(() => {
    message.channel
      .awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ['time'],
      })
      .then((message) => {
        message.reactions.removeAll();
        message = message.first();

        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === message);

        message.channel.send(`Alright, The new lfg role is ${role}!`);
      })
      .catch((collected) => {
        message.channel.send('Timeout.');
      });
  });
});
```

Also, I have a second problem which is the bot doesn't remove all the reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` is not a string- it's a `Message` object. I think you meant `message.content`

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === message.content);
```

> Also, I have a second problem which is the bot doesn't remove all the reactions

Maybe you meant `m.reactions.removeAll()`?

Answer (score 0):

To find a role by name you can simply use

```
message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Rolename");
```